# 私の or 私が to introduce a possessed topic

Tags: particles, topic

If I want to say "I lack of imagination" for example, or "My car is red" is it better to use 私の or to use 私は? what are the differences between these examples ? are they correct and natural ?

> 私は想像力が貧しい。
> 私の想像力が貧しい。
> 私の想像力は貧しい。

> 私は車が赤いです。
> 私の車が赤いです。
> 私の車は赤いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an introductory statement, 私は想像力が貧しい sounds the most natural in the first set. 私の想像力は貧しい is OK, but it is about 私の想像力 and this might sound a bit sudden unless you have been talking about someone’s imagination till that point. 私の想像力**が**貧しい sounds like you are saying “It is my imagination (not anything else's) that is poor”.

In the second set, 私の車は赤いです sounds the most natural. It is about 私の車 and rightly so. 私の車**が**赤いです has the same problem as 私の想像力が貧しい above. 私**は**車が赤いです sounds weird as an introductory statement about the color of your car. It is about 私 in contrast with another person who may have a car of a different color or some other thing that is red.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, everything is clear but i don't get exactly why for the first one the  私はXが is better and the second this is 私のXは in both case we describe something related to 私 isn't it ? Is there something like a rule ?

Comment: @Poulp: 私の想像力 is a part of 私, while 私の車 is not.